# How can I fix my shaky mouse when presenting my work computer on Microsoft Teams

Tags: remote-desktop, microsoft-teams, screen-sharing, mouse-cursor, windows-10-v1903

I have a shaky computer mouse when I am presenting in Microsoft Teams recently. These are the conditions when it happens:

1. I'm using RDP to remote in to my work computer which is running Windows 10.
2. I start or join a Microsoft Teams meeting and share a screen.
3. The screen is either my entire work computer desktop, or certain application windows like Visual Studio.
4. I move my mouse. It appears to be jittery and sometimes I see a black square flickering when I'm moving my mouse. Sometimes I also have trouble clicking on the top RDP bar (so that I can move it out of the way to click on something behind it) - the mouse will never reach the bar and keeps jumping back off the bar.

I've noticed that the 'shaky' mouse problem does not happen when I am sharing an individual application window such as Chrome, Adobe, etc. It also does not happen when I launch Teams from my home computer and share my work computer screen.
My coworker had this problem many months before I did, but it seemed like I started getting the issue after my Windows 10 Pro was updated a few months ago (to v1903).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As first try, you could in Teams Settings, temporarily turn on
"Disable GPU hardware acceleration (requires restarting Teams)".
Restart Teams to see if it makes any difference.
Undo if it doesn't.

Another try comes from the Ask Woody article
[Carboni: Jittery mouse when controlling Win10 version 1903 via RDP? There’s a solution](https://www.askwoody.com/2019/carboni-jittery-mouse-when-controlling-win10-version-1903-via-rdp-theres-a-solution/):

> Microsoft has enabled (and made default) the use of a second driver model on the system being controlled:  The WDDM model.  Up to now RDP has run off the XDDM display driver model, which is apparently better optimized for an interface that takes a noticeable amount of time to update a mouse cursor given mouse position input.  Remote connections take milliseconds, if not tens or hundreds of milliseconds.  Therein lies the problem.

The advice in the article is:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to:
  *Computer Configuration >
  Administrative Templates >
  Windows Components >
  Remote Desktop Services >
  Remote Desktop Session Host >
  Remote Session Environment*
- Set the "Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections"
  policy to Disabled
- Restart RDP.